# Create a big query view - multiple shards

Tags: view, google-bigquery, wildcard

What is the cleanest solution in Big Query to create a view from multiple tables that share the same prefix and are located in the same dataset? I'd like to have the large table updated automatically every time a new {prefix}_'yyyy_mm_dd' table is added to the dataset.

Following the documentation:

`The wildcard table functionality does not support views. If the wildcard table matches any view in the dataset, the query returns an error.`

Is creating a new table (duplicating the data) the only option then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view can query several tables:

```
create view Test.one
as
Select *
from `Test.oneM*`
```

However, query several views is not allowed:

```
Select *
from `Test.one*`
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think the key is that the view name cannot be the prefix alone, but as long as they don't match exactly views can be created as you propose.